# Which controls was this developed? ( see image ) I believe it is UITableView but can't figure how

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm new to iPhone/iPad development.

I would like to create a text app with a feature that shows images (from local files) in a list as shown in the image below. I believe it was done with `UITableView` but I don't even know how to start it. Of course I tried to search on the web, but most of the content is pretty basic...

Thanks

[image: The application is called Cool Guy]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, yow are right that can be done using UITableView but you need table view with the standard vertical rows. Visit following reference that will help you a lot.

[Vertical with standard vertical rows](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2)

Hope, this will help you...